# InfluxDB "error":"engine: field type conflict" when saving data

Tags: java, influxdb

I'm trying to save a `map` as fields in `InfluxDB`, but I'm getting following error message:

```
2017-08-10T11:28:26.816 ERROR 7 --- [pool-4-thread-1] org.influxdb.impl.BatchProcessor         : Batch could not be sent. Data will be lost
realtortagger_1                 | org.influxdb.InfluxDBException: {"error":"engine: field type conflict"}
realtortagger_1                 |
realtortagger_1                 |   at org.influxdb.impl.InfluxDBImpl.execute(InfluxDBImpl.java:511) ~[influxdb-java-2.7.jar!/:na]
realtortagger_1                 |   at org.influxdb.impl.InfluxDBImpl.write(InfluxDBImpl.java:312) ~[influxdb-java-2.7.jar!/:na]
realtortagger_1                 |   at org.influxdb.impl.BatchProcessor.write(BatchProcessor.java:248) ~[influxdb-java-2.7.jar!/:na]
realtortagger_1                 |   at org.influxdb.impl.BatchProcessor$2.run(BatchProcessor.java:278) [influxdb-java-2.7.jar!/:na]
realtortagger_1                 |   at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_144]
realtortagger_1                 |   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_144]
realtortagger_1                 |   at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) [na:1.8.0_144]
realtortagger_1                 |   at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) [na:1.8.0_144]
realtortagger_1                 |   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_144]
realtortagger_1                 |   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_144]
realtortagger_1                 |   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_144]
```

my map is a `HashMap<String, Object>` and all my values are `Integer`. 
I'm saving using following command `InfluxDB.write(dbName, RETENTION_POLICY, point)`

Comment: Your value is integer but you define type argument differently in hashmap

Comment: @atiqkhaled what do you recommend then? the method `fields` of `Point` expects a `Map<String, Object>`

Comment: So either you make value type as defined in hashmap or vice versa

Comment: @atiqkhaled but an `Integer` is already an `Object`

Comment: i am talking about key, what about your key value...key supposed to get from db

Comment: @atiqkhaled the key is a String, just like required.

Comment: Your are said in Q that `all my values are Integer` , but define type argument key as string type...

Comment: I said that I have a `HashMap<String, Object>` and the values of the `HashMap` are `Integer` and the keys are `String`